# Something's wrong with posting base64 data to express server on nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, base64

#### Perhaps I am doing this wrong.

I have a react client which-reads an image file before uploading, scales it down to a custom size and then posts the resulting base64 data to an express server.

#### Problem is the express server in the background does not read all 2MB of incoming data and just truncates it down !!!!

Resulting in generating an incomplete image file.

Request: in my browser ... u can see the content length is > 2MB

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 2218910
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---- 
WebKitFormBoundaryRBIcsbLBCFhGgZgf
```

Then Form data follows: (Which is the complete data)

```
base641: data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAyoAAAQ4CAYAAADmcCjZAAAgAE.....
```

If I just console log in my express route where I am receiving this request I don't see the full data being received.

My express app setup

```
const http = require('http')
const express = require('express')
const helmet = require('helmet')
const cors = require('cors')
const passport = require('passport')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const path = require('path')
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload')

...rest


// Setup express app
const app = express();
app.use(cors(corsOptions))
app.use(httplogger)
app.use(helmet());

// Just posting these things here ... I tried all these options
app.use(express.json({ limit: '100mb' }))
app.use(express.text({ limit: '100mb' }))
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: '100mb', extended: true }));

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

...rest
```

I am using Axios to post the data.

The entire base64 data is just 2MB long!
This shouldn't be a problem then.... 
Any Ideas? 
Why would express truncate the incoming base64 data arbitrarily....

I am receiving small base64 files ok (like 2-300kb files ok)

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue(s)

1. I was using this express-file upload package to process some file uploads. I thought it was just for file uploads but it also parses multi-part form data.
2. Once I realised this, I could'nt find a way to configure the field lengths in express-file upload (judging by the name it's prolly only for file uploads)
3. Solution:
   Used multer
   And configured the size limits of individual field sizes like this:

   `const multer = require('multer')
    const multiPartDataParser = multer({ limits: { fieldSize: 100 * 1024 * 1024 } })
    ...
    router.post('/add', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), multiPartDataParser.none(), async (req, res) => {`